# How to play audio as it's being received over a network?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, audio

I'm trying to record microphone input from a client and then send the audio data over a network. A server receives this audio data and plays the audio as it's being received.

Currently, I have a program where the client records an audio sample for 3 seconds. The audio sample is then sent to a server, which then converts the audio data into a .wav file.

**Server:**

```
import socket
import pyaudio
import wave

# Socket
HOST = socket.gethostname()
PORT = 5000

# Audio
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
frames = []

with socket.socket() as server_socket:
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Connection from " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            frames.append(data)
        except socket.error as error_message:
            break

print(frames)

with wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb') as wf:
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
```

**Client:**

```
import socket
import pyaudio

# Socket
HOST = socket.gethostname()
PORT = 5000

# Audio
CHUNK = 1024 * 4
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 3
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("Recording")

with socket.socket() as client_socket:
    client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
    while True:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        client_socket.send(data)
```

The `sounddevice` module has a documentation example called [wire.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/wire.py) that does exactly what I need the server side to do. However, the program seems to be fairly low level, and I cannot understand how to pass in audio data recorded with `pyaudio`.

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT: Solution

```
import socket
import pyaudio

# Socket
HOST = socket.gethostname()
PORT = 5000

# Audio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
CHUNK = 1024 * 4
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

with socket.socket() as server_socket:
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(1)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Connection from " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))

    data = conn.recv(4096)
    while data != "":
        try:
            data = conn.recv(4096)
            stream.write(data)
        except socket.error:
            print("Client Disconnected")
            break

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Looks like the magic comes in with `stream.write(data)`, where `data` is a bytes object received over a socket. :)

Comment: Hi @leecharles_ , can you share link to other examples of this kind?  i.e. that make use of socket

Comment: NOTE - This uses 2 channels whereas the original question uses 2 channels